# Python - Match list

Tags: python

hey i have been searching and testing different options all day and can´t get my code to work as a want it to... tried `comprehension` and `nestedfor loop` but i can´t get it right...

```
zipbytehex = [(1, 0, '0x1636'), (2, 1, '0x62'), (3, 2, '0x02'), (4, 3, '0x2F'), (5, 0, '0x1637'), (6, 1, '0x19'), (7, 2, '0x02'), (8, 3, '0x2F'), (13, 0, '0x1637'), (14, 1, '0x19'), (15, 2, '0x04'), (16, 3, '0x0A'), (17, 4, '0x1B'), (18, 5, '0x47'), (19, 6, '0xFF'), (20, 0, '0x1637'), (21, 1, '0x22'), (22, 2, '0x04'), (23, 3, '0x06'), (24, 4, '0x07'), (25, 5, '0x68'), (26, 6, '0xFF'), (718, 1, '0x59'), (719, 2, '0x02'), (720, 3, '0xFF'), (721, 0, '0x163C'), (722, 1, '0x59'), (723, 2, '0x02'), (724, 3, '0xFF'), (725, 0, '0x1635'), (726, 1, '0x59'), (727, 2, '0x02'), (728, 3, '0xFF'), (729, 4, '0x0C'), (730, 5, '0x42'), (731, 6, '0x00'), (732, 7, '0xAF')]

     new_zipbytehex =[]
        for i in zipbytehex:
            if i[1] != 0:
                new_zipbytehex.append(i)
        bytehexservi = []
        byteservi = []
        for i in zipbyteservi:
            if i[1:] == (1, '0x19'):
                byteservi.append(i[:2])
        service2, adatabyte2 = zip(*byteservi)   # inverse zip
        for new_bytehex in new_zipbytehex:
            if new_bytehex[1:] == (1, '0x19'):    # 0x19, 0x22, 0x59 or 0x62
                bytehexservi.append(list(zip(new_bytehex, service2, adatabyte2)))
        for list_bytehexservi in bytehexservi:
            #print(list_bytehexservi)
            sql = """INSERT INTO tblMsgsBytes2Parameters ([p_MsgBytes],[p_Parameter],[A_Databyte]) VALUES (?,?,?)"""
            cursor.execute(sql, *list_bytehexservi)
        cursor.commit()
        cursor.close()
        con.close()
```

Im new to python and this is as far i got in my code and now im stuck... i´m trying to extract every `tuple` that has `0x19` and the once after from my list `zipbytehex` and then write it to Access. I have managed so that every tuple with `(x, 1, '0x19')` get written over to Access but not the once after (ex `(5, 0, '0x1637'),(6, 1, '0x19'), (7, 2, '0x02'), (8, 3, '0x2F')` from `zipbytehex`) the only value i get over to Access is `(6, 1, '0x19')` not `(7, 2, '0x02') and (8, 3, '0x2F')` as i want to... i need to somehow loop through and append `(7, 2, '0x02') and (8, 3, '0x2F')` at the same time, but i don´t know how... can someone help me? Thanks

ex:
my output:

```
(6, 1, '0x19')
```

wanted output:

```
(6, 1, '0x19')
(7, 2, '0x02') 
(8, 3, '0x2F')
```

Comment: Wait, on what criterion do you pick the tuples that follow a `0x19` one? Do you just want the next two elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to understand your description, it seems to me that the data is
divided in blocks of tuples for which the second number is increasing. This leads to the following code

```
def gen_blocks(seq):
    block = []
    threshold = -1
    for item in seq:
        if item[1] < threshold:
            yield block
            block = []
        threshold = item[1]
        block.append(item)
    else:
        if block: yield block

def gen_wanted(seq):
    for b in gen_blocks(seq):
        for i, item in enumerate(b):
            if item[2] == '0x19':
                yield b[i:]
                break

zipbytehex = [(1, 0, '0x1636'), (2, 1, '0x62'), (3, 2, '0x02'), (4, 3, '0x2F'), (5, 0, '0x1637'), (6, 1, '0x19'), (7, 2, '0x02'), (8, 3, '0x2F'), (13, 0, '0x1637'), (14, 1, '0x19'), (15, 2, '0x04'), (16, 3, '0x0A'), (17, 4, '0x1B'), (18, 5, '0x47'), (19, 6, '0xFF'), (20, 0, '0x1637'), (21, 1, '0x22'), (22, 2, '0x04'), (23, 3, '0x06'), (24, 4, '0x07'), (25, 5, '0x68'), (26, 6, '0xFF'), (718, 1, '0x59'), (719, 2, '0x02'), (720, 3, '0xFF'), (721, 0, '0x163C'), (722, 1, '0x59'), (723, 2, '0x02'), (724, 3, '0xFF'), (725, 0, '0x1635'), (726, 1, '0x59'), (727, 2, '0x02'), (728, 3, '0xFF'), (729, 4, '0x0C'), (730, 5, '0x42'), (731, 6, '0x00'), (732, 7, '0xAF')]

for x in gen_wanted(zipbytehex):
    print(x)
```

The ouptut is

```
[(6, 1, '0x19'), (7, 2, '0x02'), (8, 3, '0x2F')]
[(14, 1, '0x19'), (15, 2, '0x04'), (16, 3, '0x0A'), (17, 4, '0x1B'), (18, 5, '0x47'), (19, 6, '0xFF')]
```

as expected.

Comment: thanks for trying to help! yeah sure il try ti elaborate, the whole string is actually ex, (0x1636 62 02) as you can see in zipbytehex the frist is a ID form access, the second variabel is a counter on how many hex numbers there are in each sting and the third is the hex number. So some strings can be 3 hex numbers long and some are +10 hex long (not in shown in ex)  "0x16XX XX XX XX ...". So im trying extract every string by index hex "0x19".  so it can print as shown in question "wanted print" and i can´t do that by myself, Thanks

Comment: For me the "wanted print" part still does not explain the rule. See @Right leg 's comment above. How do you know that you want 2 items after `(6, 1, '0x19')`.

Comment: thank you, this exactly how i wanted it! Sorry for having such a bad explanation on what my problem was... i have another function that splits the string (16XX ZZ YY WW ...) and gives every split a number (so 16XX = 0 , ZZ=1, YY=2 WW=3 and that number is gose (6, *here*, '0x19'), that´s how i know with number i need after. its a counter  0,1,2,3,4....

Comment: I updated the code above. Basically, there was a missing `break`.

Answer (score 0):

You could just build your list manually; this often gets the job done better than other tricks such as comprehension.

Bascially, don't put anything in your list unless a `0x19` has already been met.

```
data = []
for t in zipbytehex:
    if data:
        data.append(t)
    elif t[2] == '0x19':
        data.append(t)
```

That solution relies on a trick with the boolean value of a list.
If the `data` list is empty, put the element into it iff it has a `0x19`.
Else, `data` is not empty, which means that a `0x19` has already been put into it, so append the element, no matter what.